# Could allowing our images to be indexed hurt our web search rankings?

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, images, search-results

We are trying to solve some issues related to our SEO. When we compare ourselves to our competitors who are higher that us in SERPS, other than more backlinks (not much more), we don't see any significant differences. One thing that caught our attention, though, is that images are not being indexed for our competitors and they are for our site. So, we don't really know if it may be affecting our rankings.

So, the question is, is it possible that having multiple images and not preventing them from being crawled is affecting our rankings because, for some reason, our crawl budget is exceeded due to the images?

Comment: How many page exist on your site?  How many pages are indexed?  How many images are on your site?  Its hard to know if your crawl budget is the problem without knowing those stats.

Comment: We have ~180 indexed pages and ~350 images. They are not too many.

Comment: If there is a problem with having your images indexed it's not going to be crawl budget related. Google is willing to crawl hundreds of URLs on pretty much any site.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I supposed. I mean, our site is a small one, it doesn't make sense. But I wanted to make sure. Thank you @StephenOstermiller